# Tracking time and display it at next game

Tags: javascript, html

I have an assignment and I am a bit stuck. The assignment states:

> Modify the game so that the time is tracked and a best time (or time to beat) is stored and displayed at the end of the game and at the beginning of the next game that is played. This functionality assumes the browser is not closed and that each successive game is begun through the "Play Again?" link. The display of the time to beat is shown below.

I have all files necessary, but I am stuck in this part. Here is the code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Recipe: Drawing a square</title>
  <script src="easel.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var canvas;
    var stage;
    var placementArray = [];
    var tileClicked;
    var timeAllowable;
    var totalMatchesPossible;
    var matchesFound;
    var txt;
    var matchesFoundText;
    var tileHeight = 30;
    var tileWidth = 45;
    var border = 1;
    var globalPadding = 10;
    var margin = 10;
    var padding = 5;
    var textTiles;
    var flashcards = [
      ["a", "\u3042"],
      ["i", "\u3044"],
      ["u", "\u3046"],
      ["e", "\u3048"],
      ["o", "\u304A"],
      ["ka", "\u304B"],
      ["ki", "\u304D"],
      ["ku", "\u304F"],
      ["ke", "\u3051"],
      ["ko", "\u3053"],
      ["sa", "\u3055"],
      ["shi", "\u3057"],
      ["su", "\u3059"],
      ["se", "\u305B"],
      ["so", "\u305D"],
      ["ta", "\u305F"],
      ["chi", "\u3061"],
      ["tsu", "\u3064"],
      ["te", "\u3066"],
      ["to", "\u3068"],
      ["na", "\u306A"],
      ["ni", "\u306B"],
      ["nu", "\u306C"],
      ["ne", "\u306D"],
      ["no", "\u306E"],
      ["ha", "\u306F"],
      ["hi", "\u3072"],
      ["fu", "\u3075"],
      ["he", "\u3078"],
      ["ho", "\u307B"],
      ["ma", "\u307E"],
      ["mi", "\u307F"],
      ["mu", "\u3080"],
      ["me", "\u3081"],
      ["mo", "\u3082"],
      ["ya", "\u3084"],
      ["yu", "\u3086"],
      ["yo", "\u3088"],
      ["ra", "\u3089"],
      ["ri", "\u308A"],
      ["ru", "\u308B"],
      ["re", "\u308C"],
      ["ro", "\u308D"],
      ["wa", "\u308F"],
      ["wo", "\u3092"],
      ["n", "\u3093"]
    ];

    function init() {
      canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
      stage = new Stage(canvas);
      totalMatchesPossible = flashcards.length;
      var numberOfTiles = totalMatchesPossible * 2;
      matchesFound = 0;
      var columns = 12;
      timeAllowable = 500;
      txt = new Text(timeAllowable, "30px Monospace", "#000");
      txt.textBaseline = "top";
      txt.x = 700;
      txt.y = 0;
      stage.addChild(txt);
      textTiles = [];
      matchesFoundText = new Text(matchesFound + "/" + totalMatchesPossible, "30px Monospace", "#000");
      matchesFoundText.textBaseline = "top";
      matchesFoundText.x = 700;
      matchesFoundText.y = 40;
      stage.addChild(matchesFoundText);
      Ticker.init();
      Ticker.addListener(window);
      Ticker.setPaused(false);
      setPlacementArray(numberOfTiles);
      for (var i = 0; i < numberOfTiles; i++) {
        var placement = getRandomPlacement(placementArray);
        var pairIndex = Math.floor(i / 2);
        text = flashcards[pairIndex][i % 2];
        var textTile = drawTextTile(text, pairIndex);
        textTile.x = (tileWidth + margin) * (placement % columns) + globalPadding;
        textTile.y = (tileHeight + margin) * Math.floor(placement / columns) + globalPadding;
        stage.addChild(textTile);
        background = new Shape();
        background.x = textTile.x - padding;
        background.y = textTile.y - padding;
        background.graphics.setStrokeStyle(border).beginStroke("#000").beginFill('#eee').drawRect(0, 0, tileWidth, tileHeight);
        textTiles.push(background);
        stage.addChildAt(background);
        background.text = textTile;
        background.onPress = handleOnPress;
        stage.update();
      };
    }

    function drawTextTile(text, pairIndex) {
      textTile = new Text(text, "20px Monospace", "#000");
      textTile.pairIndex = pairIndex;
      textTile.textBaseline = "top";
      return textTile;
    }

    function randomColor() {
      var color = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
      var color2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
      var color3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
      return Graphics.getRGB(color, color2, color3)
    }

    function setPlacementArray(numberOfTiles) {
      for (var i = 0; i < numberOfTiles; i++) {
        placementArray.push(i);
      }
    }

    function getRandomPlacement(placementArray) {
      randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * placementArray.length);
      return placementArray.splice(randomNumber, 1)[0];
    }

    function handleOnPress(event) {
      var tile = event.target;
      if (!!tileClicked === false || tileClicked === tile) {
        tileClicked = tile;
      } else {
        tileClicked.graphics.beginFill('#eee').drawRect(0, 0, tileWidth, tileHeight);
        tile.graphics.beginFill('#aae').drawRect(0, 0, tileWidth, tileHeight);
        if (tileClicked.text.pairIndex === tile.text.pairIndex && tileClicked.id != tile.id) {
          tileClicked.visible = false;
          tile.visible = false;
          matchesFound++;
          matchesFoundText.text = matchesFound + "/" + totalMatchesPossible;
          if (matchesFound === totalMatchesPossible) {
            gameOver(true);
          }
        }
        tileClicked = tile;
      }
      stage.update();
    }

    function tick() {
      secondsLeft = Math.floor((timeAllowable - Ticker.getTime() / 1000));
      txt.text = secondsLeft;
      if (secondsLeft <= 0) {
        gameOver(false);
      }
      stage.update();
    }

    function gameOver(win) {
      Ticker.setPaused(true);
      var replayParagraph = document.getElementById("replay");
      replayParagraph.innerHTML = "<a href='#' onClick='history.go(0);'>Play Again?</a>";
      for (var i = 0; i < textTiles.length; i++) {
        textTiles[i].onPress = null;
      }
      if (win === true) {
        matchesFoundText.text = "You win!"
      } else {
        txt.text = secondsLeft + "... Game Over";
      }
    }

    function replay() {
      init();
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body onload="init()">
  <header id="header">
    <p id="replay"></p>
  </header>
  <canvas id="myCanvas" width="960" height="400"></canvas>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I give you 1 option for this, though you can do it also in other ways,
we declare global variables which are

`var prev_time; 
    var best_time;`

add that to your global variable declarations, then give it a value when you compute the time i guess we had that here:

```
function tick() {
  secondsLeft = Math.floor((timeAllowable - Ticker.getTime() / 1000));
  txt.text = secondsLeft;
  if (secondsLeft <= 0) {
    gameOver(false);
  }
 //compute here the total time player had and give it to prev_time
  //var totalTimePlayerplayed = some computation here which should be allowed time per player - secondsLeft
  prev_time = totalTimePlayerplayed;
  stage.update();
}

 function gameOver(win) {
  Ticker.setPaused(true);
  var replayParagraph = document.getElementById("replay");
  replayParagraph.innerHTML = "<a href='#' onClick='history.go(0);'>Play A 
  gain?</a>";
  for (var i = 0; i < textTiles.length; i++) {
    textTiles[i].onPress = null;
  }
  if (win === true) {
    matchesFoundText.text = "You win!"
    if(best_time !== NULL){
     best_time = prev_time;
    //WE assume that the last player is the best scorer
    }
  } else {
  //if there is already existing top scorer
    if(best_time < prev_time){
      best_time = prev_time
    }         
    txt.text = secondsLeft + "... Game Over";
  }
}
```

then give that time of the first player to the `prev_time`. Upon Game over or Game ended we validate here if the `best_time` has a value if not, then we give it a value of the value of `prev_time`, else we validate if the score is higher that the previous `best_time` and here's a tip, now when the player would trigger the "Play again" which I can't seem find right now, you get the variable `best_time`'s value and display it as the score to beat. Hope you get the concept and somehow it helped you accomplished what you're intended to do, but like i said before you also have some other options to do this.

Comment: thank you so much. Not sure what I am doing wrong, but is not working. I played the game locally after I put the code in, but once the game is over and I click on "Play again" the "Time to beat" doesn't display.

Comment: Oops did i not just stated above? That what i said above doesnt really mean that you should just literally copy and paste it, i actually provided you a thought on how can you accomplish it. Anyway that's for you to find out then. You're welcome anyway.